# How to configure LifeTimeManager for IContainerRegistry registrations in PrismLibrary?

Tags: prism

How to configure LifeTimeManager for IContainerRegistry registrations in PrismLibrary ?

Am I missing any using statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism’s IContainerRegistry is a general abstraction layer meant to decouple the underlying DI Container from your app, and simplify your Service registrations for the most common registrations.

Prism only has a concept of Transient and Singleton lifetimes.

```
// Registers IFoo with a Transient Lifetime
containerRegistry.Register<IFoo, Foo>();

// Registers IFoo with a Singleton Lifetime
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();

// Registers an instance as a Singleton
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(new Foo());
```

As I mentioned this is meant to cover most of your needs, though it will not cover all of your possible needs. For those scenarios you can access the underlying DI Container and access any of it’s API’s.

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().SomeContainerSpecificAPI();
```

I should also note that this existing API is being considered for some expansion in 7.2 which you can track in [Issue 1654](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1654)